# C# method for passing a list to separate string values

Tags: c#

I have a `List` object.

How can I pass these list values to separate strings? The strings always occur in the same position as follows:

```
[0] = time
[1] = location
[2] = note
```

So I need a time, location, and note string for these values.

```
driver.location = log.event_data[1];
```

It says cannot implicitly convert to string.

Comment: Would you please clarify more your question? and it it's possible can u put some code exampl?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want to do. I'm reading it for the 10th time now.

Comment: have you really tried to find the answer yourself?

Comment: Guys, you're all very smart and everything, but I think we are all just guessing here :)

Comment: looks like you need to `.ToString()` the values assuming the list is not generic or contains objects.

Comment: Yep I got it now. I don't know why it wasn't letting do that before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is unclear but it seems like the answer is

```
string time = list[0];
string location = list[1];
string note = list[2];
```

assuming that your "list" is a `List<string>` named `list`.

Comment: He could also look at the ToArray() method of List<>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx

Comment: @Justin why would you do that when it already has an Item property with an index?

Answer (score 2):

If your list is called 'list' then you can just do the following

```
string time = list[0];
string location = list[1];
string note = list[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to use classes or structures? Here's an example:

```
public class SomeClass {
     public string Time { get; set; }
     public string Location { get; set; }
     public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

Though you probably shouldn't use the `string` type to store these values, either.

If this wasn't what you meant, can you please rephrase a bit?

Answer (score 0):

If they always appear in the same location, you should be able to use the SubString() function to parse the data out, assuming it's all in one string. Is it an array? a string, or what?